# Will Firebase analytics combine the data for an iOS and an android version of the same app? If not, can I make it do so?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm looking into Firebase Analytics for an app that will have an iOS version and an Android version. These would be attached to the same Firebase Project, but would I be able to view Analytics reporting for the two combined? From research it looks like you would have to view the analytics for the apps separately and then stitch them together yourself if you want the full picture.

Also, there is a limit of 100 active sessions if using the free version with Firebase hosting the apps - can I assume there are no limits if you're hosting the app yourself?

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 9):

**Important edit:** Starting in June 2018, Google Analytics for Firebase now shows your combined project-level analytics by default. Meaning that you will now see all of your data for your iOS and Android apps combined in the same report, and if you're interested in viewing data for a specific platform, you can then just filter for that in your reports.

Regarding your second question, that "100 simultaneous connection limit for free projects" is only for simultaneous connections to the Realtime Database. You can have as many instances of your app talking to Firebase Analytics as you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Are you able to help with the other question? ie If I'm hosting the app, will the free Firebase Analytics process all the data I need, or will it only process a maximum of 100 active sessions?

Comment: Sure thing. I edited the answer to include your second question